# Cant access Coda application from command-line

Tags: command-line, coda

I am having trouble accessing Coda from command-line.  I installed the "command-line coda" plug-in, verified that my installation is in the correct location, yet I still can seem to access Coda.  Coda sits in my "Applications" folder which is the default location for the plug-in.

Anyone have have this problem? Any tips? On the [their site](http://wefoundland.com/project/command-line_coda/) it is recommended that you change the path.

```
export CODEPATH=/Applications/Coda.app
```

So I included the above line in my .bash_profile which did not help.

```
$ Coda -v
-bash: Coda: command not found
```

Thanks for any direction you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default way to open an application on a Mac is to use `open -a AppName` so you should be able to change your bash profile to use that:

```
$ open -a Coda
```

I've created a bash script (as opposed to using the plugin) that Gregory Tomlinson originally posted about (it looks like he's since taken it down but it looks like the following).

Create a new file in /bin called coda:

```
$ cd /bin
$ sudo touch coda
$ vim coda
```

Hit an `i` to enter insert mode. Then include the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo "Please specify a file to open or create"
    exit 0
else
    for ARG in $*
        do
            touch -a $ARG && open -a Coda $ARG 
        done
    exit 0
fi
```

Save and quit (hit the esc to exit insert mode then type `:w !sudo tee % >/dev/null` followed by the return key, press L for load when prompted, then type `:q` to quit). Then give that file execute permissions:

```
$ chmod u+x coda
```

Start a new Terminal window and you should be able to use:

```
$ coda filename.foo
```

Or just:

```
$ coda
```

Comment: I really appreciate all of the detail.  Thanks I will have to try  this out tonight.  --sorry I cant vote you up as I just recently learned of this site and dont have the reputation yet to allow it.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason, my paid registered Coda 2 app just wouldn't open for me this morning. I found this terminal command that worked for me:

```
open -a Coda\ 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the following in your `~/.bash_profile` file:

`alias coda='open -a "Coda 2"'`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. After installing the plug-in, I still couldn't launch coda from the command line. I took a closer look at /user/local/bin and somehow the permissions had gotten reset so I didn't have execute permissions for /user/local/bin.

I updated my permissions with:

```
sudo chmod o=rx,g=rx /usr/local/bin
```

This solved my problem. However, Coda won't launch if the specified file does not exist, which makes it hard to create a file from the command line.